# Why length property comes after the closing tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the placement of the "length" property, in a to-do-list app that I'm making as part of a JavaScript course.

**The To-Do-List:**

```
const todos = [{
    text: 'First task',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'Second task',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'Third task',
    completed: true
}]
```

**My question:**
The code below gets me a total # of tasks that still need to be completed. What I don't understand is: why does the .length property come *after* the closing "})"? I would have assumed that the code is `!todo.completed.length`, rather than `!todo.completed}).length`. I can see that only the latter works - but I'm trying to grasp *why*. Thank you!!

```
let remaining = todos.filter(function(todo){
    return !todo.completed
}).length
```

Comment: `length` property is available only for String and Arrays. Your data type is boolean (true/false).

Comment: `length` property belongs to Arrays|Strings in JS and filter method of Arrays, returns a new array for you. After gettings the new array, you use the length to learn how many left to complete :)

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array satisfying the condition in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Array.prototype.filter` returns an array. [MDN reference for `Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

For example, these two statements are equivalent:

```js
[1, 2, 3].filter(function(){
  return false
}).length
```

and

```js
[].length
```

This is because this:

```js
[1, 2, 3].filter(function(){
  return false
})
```

returns `[]`.

```js
var one = [1, 2, 3].filter(function() {
  return false
}) // Removes all elements from array

var two = []

console.log(one, one.length)
console.log(two, two.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the filter function iterates over each todo object and returns a new list of todo objects.

Each todo object is passed to the function you provide as parameter (in this case an anonymous function), only when this function returns true the todo object is added to the new list.

Since you want to know the amount of todo's that still need to be completed you return !todo.completed because this will return true when todo.completed is false.

When the filter function iterated over each object it returns the new list and that's when you can access it's length.

returning !todo.completed.lenght doesn't really make any sense because you're trying to get the length of a boolean and the filter function expects true or false.